# Assertion failure (ID cannot be null) during PreInsertEvent due to session flush when querying with findByTenantAndUserEmail

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a PreInsertEvent listener that gets triggered for every insert operation. The listener's purpose is to check user access for a tenant. When the event occurs, it tries to check the user by querying a repository method findByTenantAndUserEmail from UserOrganisationMappingJpaRepository.

Here's the code for the relevant classes:

```
@Service
public class HibernateListener {
    // ...
    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        // ...
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_UPDATE).appendListener(preUpdateListener);
    }
}

@Service
public class EntityPreInsertListener extends AbstractPreEntityListener implements PreInsertEventListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event){
        checkUser(event);
        return false;
    }
}

@Slf4j
public class AbstractPreEntityListener{
    @Autowired
    protected UserEmailCacheManager userEmailCacheManager;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public void checkUser(AbstractPreDatabaseOperationEvent event){
        // ...
        if(Boolean.FALSE.equals(userEmailCacheManager.checkUser(user, tenant))){
            log.error("...");
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class UserEmailCacheManager {
    @Autowired
    private UserOrganisationMappingJpaRepository userOrganisationMappingService;

    public Boolean checkUser(String email, Long tenant){
        //...
        UserOrganisationMappingJpaEntity userMapping=userOrganisationMappingService.findByTenantAndUserEmail(tenant, email);
        // ...
    }
}

@Repository
public interface UserOrganisationMappingJpaRepository extends AbstractTenantJpaRepository<UserOrganisationMappingJpaEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value="...",nativeQuery=true)
    UserOrganisationMappingJpaEntity findByTenantAndUserEmail(Long tenant, String email);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that during the execution of the findByTenantAndUserEmail method, it tries to flush the session, which results in an assertion failure because the ID hasn't been set yet.

Exception Message : an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in x.model entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs

Things I have tried:

I added @Transactional(readOnly=true) on the findByTenantAndUserEmail method.
I shifted from a Spring DSL query to a JPA query and then to a native SQL query, but none of these changes solved the issue.
Can anyone provide insights on why this session flush is happening during a PreInsertEvent and how to prevent the assertion failure? Any help would be appreciated!

what i need to do here is i need to check in user_organisation table if user is part of the org or not if not just log an error message